# why am I getting ORA-00936 error

Tags: oracle, select, sql-update

I can run the following statements and get the correct results:

```
select moon_phase_text (sysdate) 
  from dual;

select date_day3 
  from aday3import t1, 
       aasum_report t2 
 where t1.date_day3 = t2.game_date;
```

This statement gives me a list of days ie `22-FEB-03`

However when I am trying to update a field in a table with the following statement I get the error `ORA-00936: missing expression`

```
update aday3import 
  set moon_phase = select moon_phase_
                     (select date_day3 
                        from aday3import t1, 
                             aasum_report t2 
                       where t1.date_day3 = t2.game_date )
                    from dual;
```

Comment: Do you really have `moon_phase_` rather than `moon_phase_text` in the second version? You don't need the `select` and `from dual` parts after the `=`, you can call the function directly there, but it doesn't seem to be correlated with the row(s) you're updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going for dual. Try concatenating the moon_phase_ in the select statement itself

```
 update aday3import set moon_phase = 
                 (select 'moon_phase_'||date_day3 
                    from aday3import t1, 
                         aasum_report t2 
                   where t1.date_day3 = t2.game_date )
```

Comment: Yes in my statement it is moon_phase_text. Moon_phase_text is a function which has one parameter. The parameter is a date. The table aday3import has two fields a date field and a text field which is what I want to update with the phases of the moon using the date field. I want to use the date_day3 field to determine the phase and update the moon_phase field in the table aday3import.

Comment: Then try this. Update aday3import t1 set moon_phase = moon_phase_text(date_day3) where exists (select 1 from aasum_report t2 where t1.date_day3 = t2.game_date)